# Silly RegEx Confusion

Tags: .net, regex

Well, I've been using regular expressions with good success for a while, but I've run into a snag.

I have two string patterns that I would like to distinguish:

```
AAA(CR)(LF)*
```

vs

```
AAA BBBBB(CR)(LF)*
```

Where A is a letter, B could be any character except `(CR)`/`(LF)`, and `(CR)`/`(LF)` are carriage-return and line-feed (i.e., `0h0D/0h0A`).

I've tried the following pattern:

```
"[A-Z ]+.+\x0D\x0A\*"
```

But, aggravatingly, this matches both of the patterns above!  Shouldn't the `.+` prevent the first pattern from being matched?  As far as I understand, `+` is a greedy-match of *one or more* of the previous tokens...  Where am I going wrong?

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: In your description you do not mention space character, yet you include it you your regex. It's hard to understand what you are after when your description does not match your example. In your two sample inputs one does have space and the other does not. This is how you can distinguish between them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex matches `AAA(CR)(LF)` because the first *two* characters match `[A-Z ]+` and then the third A matches `.+`.

Although `+` indicates a greedy match, the regex engine will *backtrack* after finding `AAA` and discovering that the rest of the expression can't match. So it tries with `AA` and discovers that it *can* match the rest of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I misunderstood...

```
"[A-Z]+\x0D\x0A\*"
```

or

```
"[A-Z]+ .+\x0D\x0A\*"
```